# Does this lemma have a name?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Does the following lemma have a name? I'm asking this because the following lemma is very useful and easy to prove. So it's very likely that it has a name in the literature.

> Let $(X,\Sigma )$ be a measure space and $\mathcal{M(\Sigma) }$ be the
> set that contains exactly all measurable functions $f:X\to
> \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{M}(\Sigma)$
> is such that
>
> 1. $\chi _E\in\mathcal{M}$ (characteristic function of $E$) for all $E\in \Sigma $
> 2. $af+bg\in\mathcal{M}$ for all $f,g\in\mathcal{M}$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$
> 3. If $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{M}$ that converges pointwise, then $\lim_{n\to\infty }f_n\in \mathcal{M}$.
>
> Then $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}(\Sigma )$.

To prove the above proposition you need to use that every [measure function is a pointwise limit of simple functions](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_is_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions).

Thank you for your attention!